# Rails views handle blank values from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here I am, with my rails project, and this question strikes me.
For my User profile, some attributes will be blank and I want them to default to a specific value : if they are not set, I want my view to display the custom message and add a CSS class like "blank" around it.

I am using a Presenter, but as it acts a bit like a Helper, let's say those are helper methods.

In my Helper I have something like that :

```
def professional_information
    handles_not_set user.university, user.job do |university, job|
        content_tag(:p, university.content, class: university.error) +
        content_tag(:p, job.content, class: job.error)
    end
end
```

The `handles_not_set` is defined as followed :

```
def handles_not_set(*objects)
    o = []
    objects.each do |object|
      attr = OpenStruct.new
      if object.blank?
        attr.content = 'Not specified.'
        attr.errors = ['blank']
      else
        attr.content = object
        attr.errors = []
      end
      o << attr
    end
    yield *o
end
```

But I find this rather inelegant and I'd like to keep the code DRY (i.e : I don't want my presenter's methods to be full of 'if xxx.blank?')

Any idea on how I could improve this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: That's how I do it, and that's how Ryan Bates does it in a Railscast (your version is a bit more elaborate since it takes any number of arguments)

Comment: Oh I haven't seen this Railscast, but anyway I tend to find that a little bit too complex.

Thanks.